# ContextErrorException - Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, silex

I get the error :

```html
in VisiteurDAO.php line 48
at VisiteurDAO->findSecteurName('4') in VisiteurDAO.php line 105
at VisiteurDAO->buildDomainObject(array('id_visiteur' => 'f21', 'id_secteur' => '4', 'nom' => 'Finck', 'prenom' => 'Jacques', 'login' => 'jfinck', 'mdp' => 'mpb3t', 'adresse' => '10 avenue du Prado', 'cp' => '13002', 'ville' => 'Marseille', 'dateEmbauche' => '2001-11-10', 'Privileges' => '0')) in VisiteurDAO.php line 22
at VisiteurDAO->findAll() in routes.php line 135
at {closure}()
at call_user_func_array(object(Closure), array()) in HttpKernel.php line 153
at HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1) in HttpKernel.php line 68
at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true) in Application.php line 496
at Application->handle(object(Request)) in Application.php line 477
at Application->run() in index.php line 11
```

This is the function :

```html
 public function findSecteurName($id_secteur) {
        $sql = "select secteur_intervention from secteur where id_secteur=?";
        $row = $this->getDb()->fetchAssoc($sql, array($id_secteur));

        $rep = $row[0];
        return $rep;
    }
```

Called by :

```html
protected function buildDomainObject(array $row) {
        $visiteur = new Visiteur();
        $visiteur->setIdVisiteur($row['id_visiteur']);
        $visiteur->setIdSecteur($row['id_secteur']);
        $visiteur->setSecteurName($this->findSecteurName($row['id_secteur'])); // Here
        $visiteur->setNom($row['nom']);
        $visiteur->setPrenom($row['prenom']);
        $visiteur->setLogin($row['login']);
        $visiteur->setMdp($row['mdp']);
        $visiteur->setAdresse($row['adresse']);
        $visiteur->setCp($row['cp']);
        $visiteur->setVille($row['ville']);
        $visiteur->setDateEmbauche($row['dateEmbauche']);
        $visiteur->setPrivileges($row['Privileges']);
        return $visiteur;
    }
```

I read that error mean row[0] is empty but when I do the request on PHPMyAdmin :

> select secteur_intervention from secteur where id_secteur='4'

I get a good response : 
secteur_intervention
Paris centre

I don't understand where is my mistake. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `print_r($row)`

Comment: You used `fetchAssoc()`, so it returns an associative array, not a numeric array. Use `$row['secteur_intervention']`

Comment: Thank you @Barmar

Comment: @u_mulder Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348573/is-the-php-undefined-variable-question-overused-as-a-duplicate